# How to declare set of union? CPLEX

Tags: optimization, cplex

I am trying to build a model on CPLEX OPL and facing a problem with declaration a set of union

[5 set of union I have to declare](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCGXd.png)

I am totally new with CPLEX, I have use the method to declare a set same as the document:

```
{float} all_nodes = hubs_nodes union suppliers_nodes union clients_nodes;
{float} IH = hubs_nodes union suppliers_nodes; 
{float} A1[IH][IH];
{float} JH = clients_nodes union suppliers_nodes;
{float} A2[JH][JH];
{float} A3[hubs][hubs];   
{float} A[all_nodes][all_nodes];
```

My model declaration:

```
     minimize sum(k in hubs) operating_hub_cost[k]*allocation_variable[k][k] 
 + sum(i in suppliers, k in A3, l in A3) cih*distance[k][l]*total_quantity_flow[i]*fraction_flow_shipped[i][k][l]
 + sum(i, j in A1) cc*distance[i][j]*vehicle_traverses[i][j] + sum(i, j in A2) cd*distance[i][j]*vehicle_traverses[i][j]
 + sum(i in suppliers, k in hubs) one_unit_cost[k]*total_quantity_flow[i]*allocation_variable[i][k]
 + sum(i in suppliers, k,l in A3) one_unit_cost[l]*total_quantity_flow[i]*fraction_flow_shipped[i][k][l]
 + sum(k in hubs, i in suppliers || i in clients) vehicle_cost*vehicle_traverses[k][i];
```

And its show me the error:

> Cannot use the type {float}[hubs][hubs] with "in".

How can I declare the model without the error of A, A1, A2, A3 set in my code? Thank alot in advices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For A you could write

```
range N=1..4;

tuple arc
{
int i;
int j;
};

{arc} A={<i,j> | i,j in N};

execute
{
A;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.

Comment: can I ask you one more?
How can I write to import the data from excel file to the arc A?

Comment: You can use SheetRead. See easy examples at https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/excel-rocket-science-optimization-alex-fleischer/